# Does anyone see any possible way to slice this? (python)

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

I've been trying to speed up some numpy arrays in Python and I know for loops are really bad so you should slice them but I just can't see anyway to slice this. Maybe there's some smart trick? I am pretty inexperienced in this so would appreciate any help!

```
    def propind(in1, in2):
        return in1+M*in2
     
    for ind1 in range(M):
        for ind2 in range(N):
            for ind3 in range(M):
                for ind4 in range(N):
                    ret[propind(ind1,ind2), propind(ind3,ind4)] = tempH0s[ind1,ind2,ind4]*(ind1==ind3)
```

tempH0s is a MxNxN matrix and ret is a (MxN)x(MxN) matrix.

Comment: I am trying to understand what you are doing. What does the `propound` function do? It seems like it converts two integers into an index in a 2D matrix by multiplying the second int by the row length and the first int is the index in that row. Isn't that equivalent to simply indexing with something like `ret[ind2, ind1, ind4, ind3]`? (I reversed the orders, so that the first element gets the appropriate 'row'.)

Comment: The strategy is to first build the MxNxMxN matrix and then reshape it. For the first part, take M-many MxNxN arrays, expand them into MxNx1xN arrays, and stack them along `axis` 2. You can get the MxNxN arrays by multiplying the entire `tempH0s` with an appropriate "mask".

Comment: @Acoop the function is computing indexes for a manual reshape of MxNxMxN data into (M\*N)x(M\*N) data.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel that is correct, it's just easier for me visually.

Also, I'm not completely getting how to implement your comment. Could you elaborate just a little?

Comment: So first off, you understand that you can do `*` with two arrays of identical shapes, and it will multiply them element-wise, yes? So, imagine you had an array of all the necessary `ind1==ind3` results, for a given value of `ind3`, that you could then just multiply together with with entire `tempH0s`.

Comment: What's the difference between creating these M arrays and stacking them instead of just creating an empty MxNxMxN array and filling it in? Or is that what you mean? How else would I store M arrays?

Comment: Could you show what you want with a small example, such as `tempH0s=np.arange(18).reshape(2,3,3) `.  `ret` would be (6,6).  The `propind` indexing doesn't seem to be right.

Comment: It's sort of doing a flattening thing like Karl pointed out. If you consider the MxNxMxN matrix that has matrix elements ```tempH0s[ind1,ind2,ind4]*(ind1==ind3)```, ret is supposed to be the (M.N)x(M.N) matrix you get by flattening it.

Comment: I'm a visual person, and like see to actual arrays.  Repeating your code doesn't help.

Comment: The result I get for that definition you provided is array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  9.,  0., 10.,  0., 11.],
       [ 3.,  0.,  4.,  0.,  5.,  0.],
       [ 0., 12.,  0., 13.,  0., 14.],
       [ 6.,  0.,  7.,  0.,  8.,  0.],
       [ 0., 15.,  0., 16.,  0., 17.]])

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think I figured out what you said and wrote it in an answer below. It gives the same result so I think it's right but let me know if I am not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying something like

```
ret = np.zeros((M,N,M,N))
ind = np.arange(M)
ret[ind,:,ind,:] = tempH0s[ind,:,:]
ret = ret.reshape(M*N, M*N)
```

but the layout of values was different from what your iteration does.  I suspect that `in1+M*in2` mapping is part of the difference.

If the difference can be worked out, this should be quite a bit faster.

```
In [93]: tempH0s                                                                                     
Out[93]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]]])
```

your iteration produces

```
In [87]: foo(tempH0s,2,3)                                                                            
Out[87]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 3,  4,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  9, 10, 11,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 12, 13, 14,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 15, 16, 17,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

where as my suggestion produces:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 12, 13, 14],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 15, 16, 17]])
```

Your other code produces

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  9.,  0., 10.,  0., 11.],
       [ 3.,  0.,  4.,  0.,  5.,  0.],
       [ 0., 12.,  0., 13.,  0., 14.],
       [ 6.,  0.,  7.,  0.,  8.,  0.],
       [ 0., 15.,  0., 16.,  0., 17.]])
```

Comment: Wow that is much more concise. Yes the ordering can easily be fixed by selecting the FORTRAN order in the reshape function I think, thank you!

Comment: Also, it's faster than my solution!

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to give the solution I got using the comments to this question. It is about 20 times faster so thank you!

```
tempH0s2 = []

for z in range(M):
    tempL = np.zeros([M,N,N])
    tempL[z] = 1
    tempH0s2.append(tempH0s*tempL)

tempH0s3 = np.stack(tempH0s2, axis=2)

ret = np.reshape(tempH0s3, (M*N, M*N), order='F')
```

Comment: Glad I could lead you to a solution.